# What does "Andorinha Sinhá" mean?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, nomes, literatura

There is a children's book *O Gato Malhado e a Andorinha Sinhá* by Jorge Amado about two characters, the *Gato Malhado* and the *Andorinha Sinhá*.

I would like to know how to understand *Sinhá*. I have looked up *sinhá* in a dictionary, but I'm still not sure how it is used here (both the grammar and the meaning).

> #### sinhá
>
> [De *sinhô*]
> Substantivo feminino.
>
> 1. *Bras. Pop.* Tratamento dado pelos escravos a sua senhora; siá:
>    "Conheceram [as negras] muito dono: / Embalaram tanto sono / De tanta **sinhá** gentil!"
>    (Gonçalves Crespo, *Obras Completas*, p. 352);
>    *Conversei com **Sinhá** Maria.*

(From Aurélio.)

(Feel free to reply in Portuguese.)

Comment: Além de indicar o nome do gato e da andorinha? O livro trata do amor entre o plebeu e a senhoria, entre o gato e ave, amores proibidos.

Comment: Funny [story, that](http://houdelier.com/pdfs/gato_malhado_e_a_andorinha_sinha_sp.pdf). I wouldn't call it a children's book though. The name *Andorinha Sinhá* follows the common pattern of *Rato Mickey* and *Sapo Cocas* (Kermit the Frog); I suppose you're acquinted with this pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sinhá comes from Senhor/a (Sir). Today it's not used any anymore, but it's related, as you said, to the slave owner or somebody rich.

In this case, Sinhá has not a meaning but it's a name. Sinhá is the name of the bird. I think it's the same construction you can see in Father John, for example.

Of course, the name wasn't chosen by chance or it wouldn't make sense in a fable. The [Wikipedia topic](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Gato_Malhado_e_a_Andorinha_Sinh%C3%A1) helps to understand what it means:

> Pode-se dizer que o livro trata, metaforicamente, das diversas
>   relações e situações de cunho sócio-cultural existentes, não só
>   baianas, como brasileira e até mesmo mundial durante a primeira metade
>   do século XX; até mesmo antes dessa época e ainda hoje existentes.
>
> 'Baianamente' lembra-se do Elevador Lacerda, que divide e une ao mesmo
>   tempo o Alto e o Baixo da cidade de Salvador. O Gato, no plano baixo,
>   não pode voar e se dar a certos luxos. Em contraponto, a Andorinha
>   vive sobre os demais bichos, tendo um privilégio dado pelo berço, seu
>   lugar de origem.

It's a book about socio-cultural relationships. You have the high and the downtown. The cat lives in downtown and can't afford to achieve the high places.

The bird is named "Sinhá" because her birth right allows her to live high above in the skies, above all the other animals, just like a "sinhá" is above the slaves or the poor.

Comment: *Andorinha Sinhá* ('Swallow Sinhá')  follows the common pattern of *Rato Mickey, Sapo Cocas.* So semantically is akin to *Mickey Mouse, Kermit the Frog*, say *Sinhá Swallow* or *Sinhá the Swallow*.

Comment: Good exposition.  +1